# Multiplayer shooter: should projectiles carry the information about damage, or should the damaged entity?

Tags: performance, logic, multiplayer, conceptual

This is a conceptual question, so no code is included.

When making a multiplayer shooter, be it 2D or 3D, where there are projectile-based weapons, should each projectile contain information as to who fired it, and how much damage it should do? Or, should the entity, upon being struck by the projectile, interpret the projectile and deal damage to itself accordingly?

Basically, the question is "where should the information/code about the damage being dealt exist."

Thoughts?

Comment: I have a feeling this is going to get shot down for being too opinion-based/biased........... If you ask me, projectiles damage things, things don't damage themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO
Depends entirely on what you consider damage:
Damage potential from the projectile... definitely store in each projectile.
Damage realized upon the target... a counter to add all the damage inflicted on it by the different projectiles.
Information stored on the projectile regarding firing entity is only relevant if the firing entity is to be awarded points for sucessful hits on targets.

Comment: If you wanted the entity _firing_ the projectile to be able to receive feedback for hits, would the damaged entity use the reference included with the bullet to send a message back to the firer?

Comment: Information about the firing entity also be relevant if you want to avoid friendly fire, for example, if teammates shouldn't be able to shoot each other or enemies shouldn't be able to shoot each other. I can see this being especially important in a top-down "bullet hell" shooter.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that giving the projectile this damage provides better modularity and makes more sense logically.

**Modularity**

I used to do [M.U.G.E.N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.U.G.E.N), a fighting game engine where individual creators and teams of creators can release either full games or pieces of games. Full games are actually comparatively rare next to individual characters, stages and etc that you could copy into your own folder and have added to your roster. So if any game engine absolutely had to be designed for modularity, this was it.

How did M.U.G.E.N handle the situation? Except in specific circumstances where a particular creator wanted to do something creative or unconventional, damage amount (and a gazillion more pieces of information, like hit sound, how long to stun, what state to enter as a result) are carried by the character that delivers the attack (In a shooter, this would be equivalent to the bullet holding this information). Why?

Well, simply put, there's no way that one character could be defined so that it could tell who hit it and what attack they used when said character and attack hadn't even been *made* yet. Keep in mind, characters from 1999 and characters from 2016 are able to fight each other without issue. And almost as dauntingly (and more relevant for you), even if a character's creator could somehow precognitively know every character and every attack that would be added, it would take a *long* time and a *lot* of code to add a case for all of them.

So let's get back to the idea of a shooter. Consider that you have two kinds of bullets. One is big and deals a lot of damage (we'll call this BigBullet), while the other is small and deals a little damage (We'll call this SmallBullet). Consider also that you have two kinds of targets that these bullets can damage (We'll call them Soldier and Tank). If you store damage information in the target classes (Soldier and Tank), you have to define this information for each type of bullet for each type of target.

That is, Soldier class will have to have logic to determine which type of bullet it is and how much damage it should deal. Tank class will also have to have logic to determine which type of bullet it is and how much damage it should deal. You can reduce the redundancy of this code if you inherit both classes from a common base class, true.

But compare with the alternative. BigBullet and SmallBullet have a public damage field. The Soldier and Tank don't have to care what type of bullet it got hit by; only ask how much damage it should do. So you can remove that code altogether.

And more importantly, this allows the design to be easily expandable. If you later decide you want a new HugeBullet class that deals even more damage, all you need to do is make a new HugeBullet class. You don't have to worry about updating your target entities at all.

**Logic**

This is more opinional, but let me describe the way I look at it.

Consider the human skull. It is a work of art. It's got joints in it that allow jaw movement. It has holes in all the right places to allow sensory information to enter, and a hole for food. It's designed for durability and observation.

But it's not specifically designed for every single thing that can happen to it. It doesn't have a bullet-deflection property or an axe-survival property. It has properties that contribute to these defenses, but only in the vaguest and most general of terms. Maybe they have a general resistance to piercing, but they don't have a particular resistance to piercing by each individual type of bullet.

Ultimately the driving force behind how much damage it takes lies with the design of the weapon that strikes it. A bullet is designed to cut through flesh and bone. So organizing your code so that the bullet objects carry damage data is a more accurate simulation of reality.